# Rewriting url with results from auth_request

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use nginx to proxy requests to files stored on S3, however, I don't want to expose our bucket structure, and I need authorization that the user can access a particular file. I've managed to get all of it "working" except for the hiding of the bucket structure.

So far, the user will request https://example.com/s3/FILE_ID , which will be passed into the authorization section (using `auth_request`). It then authorizes the user, and sets headers for the `Content-Type`, S3 `Authorization` header, and other data such as the actual location on S3. I was hoping to be able to `rewrite .* $result_from_auth_request`, but it doesn't seem to work, possibly because `rewrite` and `auth_request` happen in different phases? I've got to the point where I can get a response from S3, but because I can't seem to be able to change the requested URL, the S3 authorization fails.

Basically I want to map `example.com/s3/FILEID` to `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some/bucket/path/NOT_RELATED_FILE_NAME`, but not expose the mapping to the user. Is there any way of rewriting the url based upon the result of `auth_request`?

Here's my example config:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    root /var/www;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;

    location /s3/ {
        # Auth the request first
        auth_request /auth;

        set $bucket mybucket;

        # Request will set these headers which we can pass to S3
        auth_request_set $s3_host $upstream_http_x_s3_host;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        auth_request_set $ct $upstream_http_content_type;
        auth_request_set $name $upstream_http_content_disposition;
        auth_request_set $amzAuth $upstream_http_authorization;
        auth_request_set $amzDate $upstream_http_x_amz_date;
        auth_request_set $amzContent $upstream_http_x_amz_content_sha256;
        # The auth handler sets this header as a way of specifying the the location on S3
        auth_request_set $s3path $upstream_http_x_s3_path;

        # Send these to the client so that the file will "download"
        add_header Content-Type $ct;
        add_header Content-Disposition $name;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
        # Set these to send to S3
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Host $bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $amzAuth;
        proxy_set_header x-amz-date $amzDate;
        proxy_set_header x-amz-content-SHA256 $amzContent;

        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      off;

        # !!!!---------------
        # Rewrite the url request to S3 to be the "correct" one
        # This doesn't work, "$s3path" always seems to be empty
        # !!!!---------------
        rewrite .* "/$s3path" break;

        resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 10s;

        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;

        proxy_pass https://$s3_host;
    }

    # Sometimes S3 does a redirect, so follow
    location @handle_redirect {
        error_log /dev/stdout debug;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 10s;

        set $redirect_url $upstream_http_location;
        proxy_pass $redirect_url;
    }

    location = /auth {
        #error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        internal;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://auth-service:8911/auth;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    location / {
        #error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 6000s;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://app:1854;
    }
}
```

Comment: rewrite phase happens *before* auth phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the request to varnish, then doing the url rewriting with that before handing off to s3. (I do wonder if it would have been possible to use an internal redirect without varnish though).

My confg changed as follows:

nginx.conf

```
upstream varnish_s3 {
    server varnish_cache:80;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    root /var/www;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;

    location /s3/ {
        # Auth the request first
        auth_request /auth;

        # Request will set these headers which we can pass to S3
        auth_request_set $s3_host $upstream_http_x_s3_host;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        auth_request_set $ct $upstream_http_content_type;
        auth_request_set $name $upstream_http_content_disposition;
        auth_request_set $amzAuth $upstream_http_authorization;
        auth_request_set $amzDate $upstream_http_x_amz_date;
        auth_request_set $amzContent $upstream_http_x_amz_content_sha256;
        # The auth handler sets this header as a way of specifying the the location on S3
        auth_request_set $s3path $upstream_http_x_s3_path;

        # Send these to the client so that the file will "download"
        add_header Content-Type $ct;
        add_header Content-Disposition $name;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
        # Set these to send to S3
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Host $bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $amzAuth;
        proxy_set_header x-amz-date $amzDate;
        proxy_set_header x-amz-content-SHA256 $amzContent;
        # Send to varnish
        proxy_set_header X-S3-Path $s3path;

        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      off;

       # resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        #resolver_timeout 10s;

        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;

        proxy_pass http://varnish_s3;
    }

    # Sometimes S3 does a redirect, so follow
    location @handle_redirect {
        #error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        set $redirect_url $upstream_http_location;
        proxy_pass $redirect_url;
    }

    location = /auth {
        #error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        internal;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://auth-service:8911/auth;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    location / {
        #error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 6000s;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://app:1854;
    }
}
```

varnish.default.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;

backend s3 {
    .host = "s3.amazonaws.com";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.X-S3-Path) {
        set req.url = req.http.X-S3-Path;
        return (pipe);
    }
    return (synth(401, "Forbidden"));
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    unset bereq.http.x-s3-path;
    unset bereq.http.x-varnish;
    unset bereq.http.x-forwarded-for;
}
```